# Remove bottom menus in boot screen

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, customization, custom-installer

How to remove the bottom menus: F1: Help, F2: Language... from the boot screen of ubuntu install disc?. I am trying to customize the boot screen of an ubuntu server 14.04 CD image.

[image]